# How to set up a Google Cloud Storage bucket for public use

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The IT dept at my company have set up a Google Cloud Storage bucket, but I believe they may well have set it up wrong or I may need to tweak some options.

Basically, I have a website through which I want users to upload files to the bucket (and, later on, read them). I think I've got the code sorted to allow this, but I don't think the bucket has been set up correctly.

This has to be for the general public (or at least, those uploading the files from my website). It can't be just for Google users as some of our clients have IT depts who refuse to allow them to get or use Google accounts.

So basically, how would you go about creating a bucket that would allow this? Preferably without using gsutil - just with the console.

Answer (score 0):

Granting bucket write access to the general public is a bad idea, as you are responsible for any content that gets uploaded, and it is trivial for a malicious user to increase your bill.

If you want public users to be able to upload files from your website, you should be able to use [POST object using HTML forms](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object).  In particular, take a look at the "policy document" section.